# How do you change highlighting for all files in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

In IntelliJ, you can change the highlighting level from Inspections to Syntax using a slider. However, this only applies to a single file. Is there a way to make all files use Syntax highlighting by default?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This discussion about PyCharm suggests, that JetBrains does not want you to change the default highlighting level in any of their IDEs:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206598255-Is-there-a-way-to-set-the-default-highlighting-level-to-Syntax-instead-of-Inspection-

Anyway, I found another workaround, which at least fulfills my personal demands.

The issue for me was, that I do NOT want to disable highlighting alltogether, but rather just see the important errors instead of all the checkstyle warnings etc.

To do this (in ItelliJ 2017):

1. open the settings
2. go to `Editor` - `Colors & Fonts` - `Genral`
3. select `Errors and Warnings` - `Weak Warning`
4. uncheck the `Error stripe mark`
5. hit `Apply` and close the settings window

[image]

This will disable the highlighting at the scrollbar for all "Weak Warnings".

You can also do this for the normal `Warning` if you still receive too many highlights for your needs.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you want to turn off Inspections for all files. In that case, create a new Inspection Profile with no inspections.

`Settings > Editor > Inspections` (or click on Hector and select `Configure Inspections`)

You can either enable/disable specific highlights (for instance, if you click the checkbox to the right of "java" you can disable all java inspections), or to disable them all: click on the `Manage` drop-down and select `Copy` and give it a name, say `None`

Then click the icon that looks like an Eraser with a tooltip of `Reset to Empty`

This will change it to none for the current project.  To change it for the default project, close all project windows and repeat the same steps.