# Where is the option to disable IntelliJ's syntax highlighting?

Tags: intellij-idea

I can't find the option on IntelliJ 2016.2, nor I can find anything via Google searches.

I just want to turn off syntax highlighting. Is it possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906873/how-do-you-change-highlighting-for-all-files-in-intellij may be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to **Settings >> Editor >> Colors & Fonts**.
You have to create another *Scheme* or copy an existing one with the **Save As** button.

Then, you can edit your new Scheme with the different language category under **Colors & Fonts**.
Now disable the hightlighting that you want.

Comment: EDIT: Never mind, I got it. -- When you say "disable the highlighting that you want", do you mean manually picking each color front the color palette/picker, or are there checkboxes I can literally uncheck (disable)?

Answer (score 3):

I found the way to easily disable syntax highlighting for the whole file.
In the project inspector, right click the file and choose "Mark as Plain text" that will tell IntelJ to disable all language specific features.
Very helpful, if you have a lot of errors/warnings and don't have time to figure out how to fix it, just disable it to save your eyes:)